# How to return index of Numpy array by search

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I turned a panda df to np array by 
`df2.to_numpy()`
it returns an array like:

```
array([['040F', '040J', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       ['040F', '040J', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       ['040F', '040J', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       ['040V', '007', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       ['040S', '040J', '040F', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

Note: the array "width" is not fixed
Now I get the column number which contains "040J" by

```
df2.columns[np.nonzero(df2.to_numpy() == "040J")[-1]]
Index(['V2', 'V2', 'V2', 'V2'],
      dtype='object', name=0)
```

"V2" is the column label which contains "040J" in df2 
this results skipped 4th row since it contains no "040J"

This array is OK for me, but I need to now which row does not contain "040J", how can I do it?

Comment: why not use pandas directly?

Comment: I wish there is a way to do it, but just fail to find a method using pandas alone and produces "a list of column# of each row's `040J`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Ferris showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66094895/3944322) you can do it directly in pandas, but if you prefer numpy you can do it like this:

```
a = df2.to_numpy()
(~(a=='040J').any(1)).nonzero()
```

Comment: thanks, this also works, but the result:
`(array([3], dtype=int64),)`
is a tuple, is there a way to retrieve the number "3"?

Comment: `nonzero` returns a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension. As we know that we have exactly one dimension we can safely use `...[0]`. To get the first element of the array you'll have to wrap it in a try block in case all rows contain `'040J'`: `try: i = (~(a=='040J').any(1)).nonzero()[0][0]`  `except: i = None`

Answer (score 2):

```
# which column contains '040J'
obj = (df2 == "040J").sum()
obj[obj > 0]

# which row does not contains '040J'
obj = (df2 == "040J").sum(1)
obj[obj == 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is beyond my knowledge but neat, only I don't know about the result:
`4    0
dtype: int64`  
What is `4   0`?  The return is actually `0`, an int64 data, how do I get the `4`?

Comment: that mean's `4th` rows has 0 `040J `, you can get 4 from `obj[obj == 0].index.tolist()`